# This method must return a result of type int? Farkle Game

Tags: java, findbugs

This is what I have so far. For some reason, the program won't let me return scoreOne. The method is trying to find the most repeated number and use it was points.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Farkle {

    // YOU MAY NOT DECLARE STATIC FIELDS in Farkle
    // All values must be passed to and from methods (as described by method 
    // headers)

    /**
     * <p>Users set the number of players (2-6) and score needed to win
     * for a game of Farkle.
     * 
     * <p>Players take turns rolling dice and try to accumulate the required
     * number of points. The game ends when the first player to accumulate
     * enough points is declared the winner. 
     * 
     * <p>Program execution starts here.
     * 
     * @param args UNUSED
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        /*
         * This is where you should put your welcome message and main 
         * program loop. Make sure to match your output to what's described
         * in the project specification.
         */

        System.out.println("Welcome to Farkle.");
        // Number of players for this game
        System.out.print("How many players? ");
        int numOfPlayers = in.nextInt();
        while (numOfPlayers > 6 || numOfPlayers < 2) 
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid answer. Farkle may be played by 2-6 players. ");
            System.out.print("How many players? ");
            numOfPlayers = in.nextInt();
        }
        // User inputs points needed to win
        System.out.print("How many points do you need to win? ");
        int neededPoints = in.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Game will play until " + neededPoints + " points");
        System.out.println("It is now player 1's turn. ");

        //User inputs command for game
        System.out.print("Enter command: ");
        String command = in.next();
        boolean commandLoop = true;
        int dice [] = new int [6];
        int allDice [] [] = new int [10] [10];
        int currentRollNum = 0;
        int scoreOne = 0;
        int scoreTwo = 0;
        while (commandLoop) {
            if (command.equals("exit"))
            {
            System.out.println("Game over.");
            break;
            }
            if (command.equals("help") || command.equals("HELP")) 
            {
            printHelp();
            command = in.next();

            }


            if (command.equals("roll"))
            {
                int arrayOne [] = rollDice(dice, allDice, currentRollNum);
                System.out.println("Your roll: [" + arrayOne[0] + ", " + arrayOne[1] + ", " + arrayOne[2] + ", " + arrayOne[3] + ", " + arrayOne[4] + ", " +arrayOne[5] + "]");


                int var = scoreDice(arrayOne);

                break;
            }


            if (command.equals("turn"))
            {
                int arrayTwo [] = rollDice(dice, allDice, currentRollNum);
                System.out.print("Your roll: [" + arrayTwo[0] + ", " + arrayTwo[1] + ", " + arrayTwo[2] + ", " + arrayTwo[3] + ", " + arrayTwo[4] + ", " +arrayTwo[5] + "]");
                command = in.next();

            }

            }
    }
    private static void printHelp() {

        System.out.println("\"roll\" - roll the dice");
        System.out.println("\"finish\" - terminate the current turn");
        System.out.println("\"dice\" - print the current dice");
        System.out.println("\"turn\" - print the current turn so far");
        System.out.println("\"scores\" - print scores");
        System.out.println("\"help\" - print this help menu");
        System.out.println("\"exit\" - terminates the game");

    }
    private static int[] rollDice(int[] dice, int[][] allDice, int currentRollNum) {
        int dice1 = Dice.rollDie(true);
        int dice2 = Dice.rollDie(true);
        int dice3 = Dice.rollDie(true);
        int dice4 = Dice.rollDie(true);
        int dice5 = Dice.rollDie(true);
        int dice6 = Dice.rollDie(true);

        int [] newlyRolled= new int [6];
        newlyRolled [0] = dice1;
        newlyRolled [1] = dice2;
        newlyRolled [2] = dice3;
        newlyRolled [3] = dice4;
        newlyRolled [4] = dice5;
        newlyRolled [5] = dice6;

        return newlyRolled;

    }   

    private static void printDice(int[] dice) {





        }

    /**
     * Print a 2D-array to the console.
     * [turn1dice1, turn1dice2, turn1dice3, turn1dice4, turn1dice5, turn1dice6, ]<br />
     * [turn2dice1, turn2dice2, turn2dice3, turn2dice4, turn2dice5, turn2dice6 ]<br />
     * [2, 4, 4, 3, 1, 6, ]<br />
     * [1, 3, 2, 5 ]<br />
ram allDice The 2D-array of dice (representing all rolls for this 
     * turn) to be printed to the console
     */


    private static void printDice(int[][] allDice) {




    }

    /**
     * Print a record of all dice rolled so far during this turn
     * and the number of points earned so far.
     * 
     * <p>Output should be formatted as follows (where X is the currentTurnScore):<br />
     * [turn1dice1, turn1dice2, turn1dice3, turn1dice4, turn1dice5, turn1dice6, ]<br />
     * [turn2dice1, turn2dice2, turn2dice3, turn2dice4, turn2dice5, turn2dice6 ]<br />
     * etc.<br />
     * X points so far this turn.<br />
     * 
     * @param allDice The 2D-array of dice (representing all rolls for this 
     * turn)
     * @param currentTurnScore The current score for this turn
     */



    private static void printTurn(int[][] allDice, int currentTurnScore) {



    }

    /**
     * Compute the score for the currently rolled dice. 

     * 
     * Dice should be scored using the following algorithm:
     * <ol>
     * <li>Find all groupings of dice of the same number (die showing 0 do not count)
     * <li>The largest group (> size 1) of dice of the same number will be worth 
     * points; the number of points is equal to the number of dice in the group. 
     * <li>If more than one die number has the same size group, the smallest die 
     * number should be used.
     * <li>If no groups > size 1 exist, 1 point can be earned if there is a die 
     * with the number 1. 
     * <li>Otherwise, 0 points are earned.
     * </ol>
     * 
     * <p>Dice that are found to be worth points should be set to 0, indicating
     * that they are no longer available to be re-rolled later in this turn.
     * 
     * <p>For example:<br />
     * [2, 3, 4, 3, 5, 6]<br />
     *  is worth 2 points (for the two 3s)<br />
     *  resulting dice = [2, 0, 4, 0, 5, 6]<br /><br />
     * [2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 6]<br />
     *  is worth 2 points (for the two 2s)<br />
     *  resulting dice = [0, 3, 4, 3, 0, 6]<br /><br />
     * [0, 3, 4, 2, 0, 6]<br />
     *  is worth 0 points (because there are no groups and no die showed 1)
     * 
     * @param dice The 1D-array of current dice.
     * @return The score earned by dice.
     */
    private static int scoreDice(int[] dice) {

        int numOne = 0;
        int numTwo = 0;
        int numThree = 0;
        int numFour = 0;
        int numFive = 0;
        int numSix = 0;

        for ( int i=0; i<dice.length; i++)
            {
                switch (dice[i]){
                case 1: numOne++; break;
                case 2: numTwo++; break; 
                case 3: numThree++; break;
                case 4: numFour++; break;
                case 5: numFive++; break;
                case 6: numSix++; break;
                }
                int scoreOne = 0;
                if (numOne > numTwo && numOne > numThree && numOne > numFour && numOne > numFive && numOne > numSix) 
                {
                numOne = scoreOne;

                }

                else if (numTwo > numOne && numTwo > numFour && numTwo > numFive && numTwo > numSix && numTwo > numThree)
                {
                numTwo = scoreOne;
                }
                else if (numThree > numOne && numThree > numTwo && numThree > numFour && numThree> numFive && numThree > numSix){
                numThree = scoreOne;
                }
                else if (numFour > numOne && numFour > numTwo && numFour > numThree && numFour > numFive && numFour > numSix){
                numFour = scoreOne;
                }
                else if (numFive > numOne && numFive > numTwo && numFive > numThree && numFive > numFour){
                numFive = scoreOne;
                }

                return scoreOne;

                }

    }

    /**
     * Resets all dice to an "unrolled" value of 1.
     * 
     * @param dice The 1D-array of dice to be reset
     */
    private static void resetDice(int[] dice) {

    }   

    /**
     * Resets all dice rolls to an uninitialized value of -1.
     * 
     * @param allDice The 2D-array of dice to be reset
     */
    private static void resetDice(int[][] allDice) {

    }

    /**
     * Checks how many dice are still available to be rolled. A die is no longer
     * active if it has a value of 0.
     * 
     * @param dice The 1D-array of dice to check
     * @return The number of dice that are still available to roll
     */
    private static int numRemainingDice(int[] dice) {




    }


    /**
     * Print all current scores to the console.
     * 
     * <p>Output should be formatted as follows:<br />
     * Player 1: X<br />
     * Player 2: X<br />
     * etc.<br />
     * where player 1's score is stored at index 0 in the array.
     * 
     * @param scores The 1D-array representing player's current scores.
     */
    private static void printScores(int[] scores) {



    }

    /**
     * Determines if one of the players has accumulated
     * enough points (>= neededPoints) to win. 
     * 
     * @param scores The 1D-array of current scores
     * @return The index of the winning player if one exists, else -1
     */


    private static int findWinner(int[] scores, int neededPoints) {



    }
}
```

Comment: findWinner is typed to return an `int`, but you don't return an int from it. Ditto for numRemainingDice and scoreDice (in scoreDice you return an int in _some_ code paths, but you have to return an int in _all_ code paths. What happens if `dice` is an empty array, so that the body of the `for` loop never runs?)

Comment: If `dice.length` is zero, it will return nothing.

Answer (score 1):

If the length of the dice array is 0 (if it is empty), that for loop will never run. This means there is a chance of not being able to return anything which is not allowed. To solve this, you must add a return statement to possible code paths, including one where the for loop never executes. To do this, add a `return 0` at the end of your method, after the for loop.